# Solve this equation for x

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've come up with an equation whilst solving a problem but I need to rearrange it for $x$. Putting it in Wolfram Alpha doesn't give me anything. This is the equation

$$(1+x)^c - (1-x)^c = d.$$

$c,d$ are real and larger than 0.

I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Without knowing $c$, what you are trying to do is impossible. And, in fact, for many values of $c$ and $d$, there may not even be a unique solution.

Comment: Is $c$ a real or an integer ?

Comment: $c,d$ are real and larger than 0.

Comment: When you say "Rearrange for x", do you mean Solve the equation for x?

Comment: Yes, I do mean that. I have no idea where to start.

Comment: @5xum could you tell me or link me an easy explanation as to why it's impossible?

Comment: @ignoramus Well, it's possible for $c=2$, for example, since the expression simplifies a lot. But for $c=5$, what you get is an equation which demands that you find a root of a fifth degree polynomial, which is not always possible (in a closed form) and can only be done numerically.

Comment: @5xum Ah ok, I probably did something wrong then since the eventual answer needs to be closed-form.

Comment: @ignoramus There most certainly is no closed form with both $c$ and $d$ being free variables.

Answer (score 2):

In first step, let $c\in \mathbb N$. Then, your equation: $(1+x)^c-(1-x)^c=d$ is always a polynomial form odd degree. So, in this case, for every given $d$, you can find a real $x$ satisfy $(1+x)^c-(1-x)^c=d$. Now, Let $c\gt0$ and more: $c\in \mathbb{R-N}$. Then, you should have: $1+x\ge0$ And $1-x\ge0$. So, $-1\le x\le 1$. Now, consider the function: $$f(x)=(1+x)^c-(1-x)^c$$ For every  $x\in (-1,1)$, the function $f$ is increasing. So, $f$ has the minimum value $-2^c$ at the point: $x=-1$ and has the  maximum value $2^c$ at the point: $x=1$. Which means, for every $d\in [-2^c,2^c]$, the equation: $(1+x)^c-(1-x)^c=d$ has a unique solution.

Comment: $ x = \pm 1 $ for all $d$ values

Comment: Let $x=-1$ then, $(1+x)^c-(1-x)^c=-2^c\lt 0 $,